# Use thymeleaf template for some pages and rest for some for building gradle project

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am new to this please someone tell me whether I can use Thymeleaf template for some pages and REST for some for building Gradle project?

I created my login page retrieving through MySQL database using Thymeleaf template now for adding other information in my database I want to use RESTful services,

Comment: i am new to spring , sorry if i am asking some vague question, but i didn't cleared my doubt, please help me

Comment: Simply put, Yes You can.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do both have REST controllers, and also have other controllers that serve up Thymeleaf pages.